# Finding format of data source used in official Carto example

Tags: carto

I'm trying to apply my own data to [this example](https://github.com/CartoDB/carto-vl-training/blob/master/08-animation.md), but I'm not sure what format the original data was in. I've checked through Carto's stock datasets in the web dashboard, but I can't find it.

Is there somewhere I could find the bird_journey data used in the Carto training guide, or is there a way I could somehow access it through javascript using sources?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a link to that example's bird_journey dataset: https://cartovl.carto.com/dataset/bird_journey

Answer (score 1):

More explanation about the origin of the data for the same example is available on this page:

https://carto.com/developers/carto-vl/v0.10.0/guides/animate-your-visualizations/